# how to set name attribute of hidden field in tag-adding plugin

Tags: php, jquery, tags

I am using [jquery](http://textextjs.com/manual/examples/tags-adding.html) plugin .  Plugin is working great but I need to post the data of **hidden** field (when I add any tag value.It is saving in hidden field via jquery) on next page via the **PHP**  but problem is that this hidden field do not have name attribute. How can I set it's name ?

Please help!

Comment: post your code what you are trying.

Comment: Paste some Code please

Comment: I do not know how to set name attribute since I do not have idea of its .js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give name to your textarea and it will show it in your hidden input

```
  <textarea id="textarea" name="yourname" class="example" rows="1"></textarea>
```

so the hidden input name will be yourname.

and in PHP you can take it as

```
$_POST['yourname']
```

**updated**

here is the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/thSsj/1/)

Comment: check out the update i ahve created fiddle too...the hidden value name is the one that you give to textarea...

Comment: how can I set id to hidden field. Name is done but i am in need of id too.

Comment: may i know why you need ID ?? if its for selecting in jquery.. then use name itself.. `$('input[name="yourname"]').val()`..:)